# Can the host toggle switching between cameras in a Chime meeting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-chime

Is it possible for the host of a Chime meeting created via the SDK, to switch another meeting attendee's camera from front to back?

Comment: I wanted the host to turn someone else's camera. I was wondering if that would be possible, I also thought that it could be against privacy, that's why I asked

Answer (score 1):

No, it's against user privacy to allow the host to control someone else's camera. No meeting software e.g. Google Meets, Microsoft Teams, Cisco Webex etc. has this functionality.

[`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) is a *client-side* JavaScript API. Even if the host has permission, the user themselves need to trigger the switch without some aspect of remote control, as they are the ones in control of the camera hardware.